# Построение кода по диаграмме

Tags: проектирование, case, диаграммы

Задали курсовую в университете - построение кода по DFD(Data Flow Diagram или диаграмма потоков данных). Изучив предметную область (в частности [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8026845/how-to-turn-dfd-into-code)), я пришёл к выводу, что диаграммы такого вида - это логические диаграммы, которые *только* моделируют область потоков данных. То есть, чтобы переносить это дальше, надо строить другие диаграммы, к примеру, UML, где уже отображать области, отмеченные на DFD - диаграмме.

Собственно, вопрос: подскажите, насколько я не прав, и как делают правильно, а также - реально ли ( и делают ли вообще так) строить код по DFD - диаграмме? Если да, то можно пример софта, или алгоритм, что угодно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно, не правильно это дело вкуса, опыта, сроков, финансирования, требований и так далее.

Надо говорить не о "правильности" подходов к созданию ПО, а об удовлетворении требований поставщика задачи (будь-то препод, или заказчик).

И вот для удовлетворения этих требований, если по предоставленной информации вы сумеете сделать то, что от вас требуется, то что ещё нужно (если и так понятно, то зачем плодить лишнюю бюрократию и тратить драгоценный ресурс - время)?

Если же предоставленая информация вызывает закономерные вопросы, то задавайте их, - используйте различные диаграммы и схемы, а также применяйте методики сбора и структурирования требований. И все это до тех пор пока задача (или её, независимые друг от друга, части) не станет вам понятной.

Все это должно быть не само по себе (не ради ибд), а ради одной единственной цели - удовлетворение требований заказчика, не больше и не меньше.

Comment: Прекрасный, замечательный ответ! Спасибо, запомню как цитату(никакого сарказма, очень понравились слова)